# Using UNION to make 3 different outputs

Tags: mysql, sql

In my database, I am trying to find the highest price model for each maker. I want to make a query so my output lists the maker, the model and the price. As of now, I am able to get the output of the maker and the price, but I am unsure what to do in order to get my model to show up in the result.

Here is my code and current output:

```
Select Product.Maker, Max(U.price)
From (SELECT Price price, Model model
From Desktop
UNION ALL
SELECT Price price, Model model
From Laptop
UNION ALL
SELECT Price price, Model model
From Printer) as U
INNER JOIN Product
ON Product.Model = U.model
GROUP BY Product.Maker
```

Output:

```
Maker Max(U.price) 
A          899 
B          1099 
C          1399 
D          1699 
E          1599
F          1799
G          1899
H          80
I          259
```

I want this output to display the model number alongside the Maker and the Price such as:

```
Maker    Price    Model
x        y        z
```

Here is the database schema, hope this helps! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Computer Database schemas:

Product( maker, model, type)
Desktop( model, speed, ram, hd, price)
Laptop( model, speed, ram, hd, screen,price)
Printer( model, color, type, price)
```

I would be able to post the tables of all the information if that is helpful as well.

Comment: which database platform are you on? sql-server, postgres, mysql?

Comment: @sqlZimbI am using MySQL on a Linux Virtual Machine.

Comment: What's happen if you have 2 products that have the same higher price for a maker ? Do you want both ?

Comment: @Fabien TheSolution I would prefer to have both products be in the output, but if not I would want at least one.

Comment: Do you have acces to the DB design ? If yes, I suggest to move the price field in the product table instead of each "sub" table. Your query will be less complicated. Also, it seems that you will get some trouble if you have two different makers that have the same model "code"...

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have access to the DB design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the good track. You need to extract only the top row of each Maker. With [group_concat](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) you can roll up the model column into a comma-separated string per-maker, ordered by its price:

```
group_concat(Model order by Price desc)
```

That’ll give you all the models, with the highest price model first.
Then, using [substring_index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) — which grabs the first word before the comma — you can extract out only the first model.

```
select 
  Maker, 
  substring_index(
       group_concat(Model order by Price desc), ',',1) model,
  max(Price) Price
from (
  Select Product.Maker Maker, Product.Model Model, Max(U.price) Price
  From (SELECT Price price, Model model
        From Desktop
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Price price, Model model
        From Laptop
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Price price, Model model
        From Printer) as U
  INNER JOIN Product ON Product.Model = U.model
  GROUP BY Product.Maker, Product.Model
) t
group by Maker
```

See this page for the concept explanation : [Selecting Only One Row Per Group](https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/selecting-only-one-row-per-group.html)

[SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/09f462/24)